# Looping through a df and storing values in a new df

Tags: r

I have the following df

```
 COMPETITION               TEAM1             TEAM2 pointsH pointsA     DATUM
1 Premier League   Manchester United      Swansea City       0       1 16-8-2014
2 Premier League Queens Park Rangers         Hull City       0       1 16-8-2014
3 Premier League          Stoke City       Aston Villa       0       1 16-8-2014
```

What I would like to do i create a new df containing the date the teamname and whether or not they won. So therefore I try:

```
rateclub <- function(df, club) {

df_m <- data.frame(Win=character(), 
               date=character(), 
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

     df_m$win <- ifelse(((df$TEAM1 == club && df$pointsH == 1)|| (df$TEAM2 == club && df$pointsA == 1)) , "W", "L") 
    df_matches$DATE <- df$DATUM
}
```

But this gives me:

```
  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "win", value = "L") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

My expected output should be

```
"Manchester United", "L", 16-8-2014
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized, no need to put it in a `for` loop

Comment: but if I run it without ifelse i still get the error. Any feedback on my actual question?

Comment: It's because the dataframe `df_matches` has no row and you try to assign  it a value

Comment: @etienne Exactly. I think you posted your comment while I was typing my answer. If you want to post an answer with a correct definition of the dataframe please let me know and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @RHertel: thanks for the offer but you covered everything in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the definition of the data.frame `df_m`, which in the OP has zero rows. Unless the code is changed significantly, it is necessary (and better) to specify the required rows at the beginning.
In the code below, the pertinent rows are stored in `df_rows` and the data.frame `df_m` is initialized with the corresponding number of rows.
Finally, the date in `df_m` is selected from `df`only for those rows.

```
rateclub <- function(df, club) {
  df_rows <- which(df$TEAM1==club | df$TEAM2==club)
  df_m <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(df_rows),ncol=3),stringsAsFactors = F)
  colnames(df_m) <- c("team","win", "date")
  df_m$team <- club
  df_m$win <- ifelse(((df$TEAM1[df_rows] == club & df$pointsH[df_rows] == 1) | (df$TEAM2[df_rows] == club & df$pointsA[df_rows] == 1)) , "W", "L") 
  df_m$date <- df$DATUM[df_rows]
  return(df_m)
}
```

Which yields:

```
> rateclub(df, "Manchester United")
#               team win      date
#1 Manchester United   L 16-8-2014
```

Hope this helps.

**data**

```
text <- " COMPETITION               TEAM1             TEAM2 pointsH pointsA     DATUM
'Premier League'   'Manchester United'      'Swansea City'       0       1 16-8-2014
'Premier League' 'Queens Park Rangers'         'Hull City'       0       1 16-8-2014
'Premier League'          'Stoke City'       'Aston Villa'       0       1 16-8-2014"
df <- read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Any thoughts @RHertel

Comment: @FrankGerritsen I have changed the answer according to your edits. Please check if this version provides the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` version - more legible (at least to me;), converts the whole table at once:

```
text <- " COMPETITION               TEAM1             TEAM2 pointsH pointsA     DATUM
'Premier League'   'Manchester United'      'Swansea City'       0       1 16-8-2014
'Premier League' 'Queens Park Rangers'         'Hull City'       0       1 16-8-2014
'Premier League'          'Stoke City'       'Aston Villa'       0       1 16-8-2014"
df <- read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(where, team, TEAM1, TEAM2) %>%
  mutate(won = (where == "TEAM1" & pointsH == 1) | (where == "TEAM2" & pointsA == 1) ) %>%
  select(-starts_with("points"))
```

Gives (`where` values could be changed to home/away, but I did not want to clutter the answer):

```
     COMPETITION     DATUM where                team   won
1 Premier League 16-8-2014 TEAM1   Manchester United FALSE
2 Premier League 16-8-2014 TEAM1 Queens Park Rangers FALSE
3 Premier League 16-8-2014 TEAM1          Stoke City FALSE
4 Premier League 16-8-2014 TEAM2        Swansea City  TRUE
5 Premier League 16-8-2014 TEAM2           Hull City  TRUE
6 Premier League 16-8-2014 TEAM2         Aston Villa  TRUE
```